# Expand Collapse Icons with Vue Js and Bootstrap

Tags: laravel, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js

I have a Bootstrap accordion with the expand collapse panels,which works fine.
But when expanded it should display minus icon which is not working well for me.
When I click to expand all the panel's icons are changed to minus instead of just changing the one which was expanded.
I have my code in the Vue JS template as below

Am calling the toggle function onclick to toggle the icons, but its doing it for all the other panels too.

How can I fix this? Thanks in advance.

```
Vue.component('accordion', {
        data: function () {
            return {
                alerts: [],
                sound: '',
                collapsed:true
            }
        },
        template: `
                    <div>
                      <div v-for="(alert, index ) in alerts" class="panel panel-default">
                          <div class="panel-heading" v-bind:style="'background-color:'+alert.color" role="tab"  v-bind:id="'heading'+index"  >
                                  <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion"
                                           v-bind:href="'#collapse'+index" aria-expanded="true" v-on:click="toggle">
                                             <i id="collapseExpand" v-show="collapsed" class="more-less fa fa-plus"></i>
                                             <i id="collapseExpand" v-show="!collapsed" class="more-less fa fa-minus"></i>
                              <h4 class="panel-title">@{{ alert.description }}</h4></a>
                          </div>
  <div v-bind:id="'collapse'+index" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel">
                          <div class="panel-body">
                              <div>@{{ alert.comment }}</div>
<div class="row">
                                            <form v-bind:id="'form_'+index"  v-bind:name="'form_'+index" v-bind:action="route"  method="POST" style="display: inline;">
                                                <input type="hidden" name="_token" :value="csrf">
                                                <input type ="hidden" v-bind:id="'trigger_id_'+alert.triggerid" name = "trigger_id" v-bind:value="alert.triggerid">
                                                <div class="col-lg-12">
                                                    <div class="input-group">
                                                        <input type="text" v-bind:id="'ack_msg_'+alert.triggerid" name="ack_msg" class="form-control"
                                                               placeholder="Acknowledge Message...">
                                                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                                                            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Save</button>
                                                        </span>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </form>
                                        </div>
                          </div>
                                <div class="panel-footer">@{{ alert.timestamp }}</div>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                          <input type="hidden" id="audioFile" name="audioFile" v-bind:value="sound">
                   </div>`,
        mounted: function () {
            this.loadData();
            setInterval(function () {
                this.loadData();
            }.bind(this), 1000);
        },
        methods: {
            loadData: function () {
                $.get('{{ route('getAlertsPersistent') }}', function (response) {
                    this.alerts = response;
                    this.sound = this.alerts[0].sound
                }.bind(this));
            },
            toggle(){
                this.collapsed = !this.collapsed ;
            }
        },

    });
    new Vue({el: '#accordion'});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to separate your accordion item that you want to loop. In that way you can have isolated states in each component.

```js
<div>
    <accordion-item 
        v-for="(alert, index) in alerts"
        :alert="alert"
        :key="index">
    </accordion-item>
</div>
```

inside your `<accordion-item/>` you should have `collapsed` inside your `data`

The other way around is storing the toggled items in array.

```js
export default {
    data: () => ({
        toggled: []
    }),
    methods: {
        isActive (item) {
            return this.toggled.indexOf(item) >= 0
        },
        toggleItem (item) {
            const index = this.toggled.indexOf(item)

            if (index >= 0) {
                this.toggled.splice(index, 1)
                return
            }

            this.toggled.push(item)
        }
    }
}
```

So you can use it now as follows

```html
<a 
    role="button" 
    data-toggle="collapse" 
    data-parent="#accordion"
    v-bind:href="'#collapse'+index" 
    aria-expanded="true"
    v-on:click="toggleItem(index)">
    <i 
       :class="[isActive(index) ? 'fa-minus' : 'fa-plus']"
       class="more-less fa"></i>
       <h4 class="panel-title">@{{ alert.description }}</h4>
</a>
```

btw you're looping an `id=collapseExpand` which will cause you problem. instead try `:id="'collapseExpand' + index"`

Comment: Thanks @Darick, you saved my day :)